# Interpreting open statements with multiple free variables and distinct quantifiers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

The textbook I am using to self-learn logic has a few problems that I am really struggling with. I feel strongly that solving them is critical to build the necessary intuition but every time I try a solution and match it with the answers at the back of the book, I am surprised to find out that I was wrong. I've noticed that I struggle particularly with questions that ask to translate symbolic statements that involve multiple free variables and are bounded by both quantifiers (existential and universal).

> Let $p(x, y)$ denote the open statement "$x$ divides y", where the
> universe for each of the variables $x, y$ comprises all integers.
> Translate each of the following into plain english and specify whether the statement is true. If false, provide a counter-example.

1. $\forall y \space \exists x \space  p(x, y)$
2. $\exists y \space \forall x \space p(x, y)$
3. $\forall x \space \forall y \space p(x, y)$

Looks like any technique that I develop to interpret convoluted statements tends to work fine for one statement but breaks down completely for another. I would highly appreciate if someone could share a consistent technique that always works.

My translations for above statements:

1. There exists at least one $x$ that divides all $y$.
2. There exists at least one $y$ that is divided by all $x$.
3. For all $x,y$, if $x \vert y$ and $y \vert x$, then $x = y$.

Comment: It is quite simple: 1) "for ever y, there is an x such that (x divides y)"

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am failing to articulate what I am struggling with, maybe that is because I myself am not sure. Can you answer why isn't 1) "there exists x that divides all y"?

Comment: Or mine and yours are equivalent statements?

Comment: Because the formula starts with "for every y". And no, they are not: compare the following in the domain of naturals: "for every natural n there is a greater natural m" i.e. $\forall n \exists m (n < m)$ with "there is a natural m that is greater than every natural n" i.e. $\exists m \forall n (n < m)$.

Comment: @Devashish $\forall y \exists x$ transcribes directly for Mauro's comment. It is different from your transcription, because "for every $y$ there is an $x$" and "there exists $x$ such that for all $y$" come in a different order. The significance of the order is that *given* $y$, $x$ can depend on $y$. For instance, $x$ could be provided as some formula that depends on $y$. In your transcription, that can't happen, because you referred to $x$ before $y$ was introduced.

Comment: In that case, is 2) wrong too? The correct statement should be "there exists an integer $y$ for every $x$, such that $x$ divides $y$", (or, every integer $a$ divides at least one integer $b$)? This statement should be true. But my book says the statement is false. What am I doing wrong this time?

Comment: Wait no, $x = 0$ divides no integer, my bad.

Comment: @Devashish 2) is correct. The easy transcription is "there exists $y$ such that for all $x$, $x$ divides $y$". I really recommend writing down this form first, it requires no thought and it's very hard to get wrong. What you write in your comment is "every integer $a$ divides some integer $b$" - said differently, "for all $a$, there exists $b$, such that $p(a, b)$". That's different from 2).

Comment: Thank you so much. Folks here are doing great work helping us noobs to self-study math. I would write a poem to offer my gratitude but that will be extremely off-topic :)

Comment: Logical formulas are written and read left to right. "$\forall y\,\exists x\,p(x,y)$" means "for all y there is an x such that p(x, y)". It doesn't begin with "there is an x".  Alphabetical order of variables is of course irrelevant.